# Xcode error: "passing 'float' to parameter of incompatible type id"

Tags: objective-c

I have set a variable `radius` in my Objective C implentation file:

`float radius = MIN(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y) / 2.0;`

I am trying to check the value of it, so I added in:

```
NSLog(radius);
```

Xcode gives me this error at the end of the line:

`Passing 'float' to parameter of incompatible type id`

Why is it expecting an 'id', and why can't it log a float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
NSLog(@"%f", radius);
```

[It appears that NSLog only accepts a formatted string.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)